# Json API Include filter not working

Tags: json-api, jsonapi-resources, jsonapi-serialize

I have an issue, I want to apply filter on included data but it's not working

here is the scenario

API :

```
/patient/257?include=patientdiagnosis&filter[patientdiagnosis.IsDeleted]=0
```

or

```
/patient/257?include=patientdiagnosis&filter[patientdiagnosis.IsDeleted]=false
```

but in response, I didn't get the filter data

Data of include

```
"included": [ { "type": "patient-diagnosis", "id": "17", "attributes": { "PatientDiagnosisId": 17, "PatientID": 257, "ICDID": 2, "IsActive": false, "DiagnosisDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00", "CreatedDate": "2017-08-25T03:37:46.0239768", "CreatedBy": 1, "UpdatedBy": null, **"IsDeleted": true**, "DeletedBy": null },
```

Answer (score -2):

The `include` parameter is meant to include any related resources to the primary data. If you mean to get all the `patient-diagnosis` resources that haven't been deleted for patient 257, perhaps you should structure your request another way:

```
/patient/257/patient-diagnosis?filter[isdeleted]=false&include=patient
```